# PageSpeed Insights Crashing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, crash, out-of-memory, pagespeed-insights

Issue:
Pagespeed Insights has basically become unusable.  Switching from Mobile to Desktop crashes the site 9/10 times with "Not enough memory to open this page."

This is not a new issue, it has been this way for 6 months to a year.  I just kept expecting someone must know about the problem and they would fix it.  Nope!

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xviw0.png)

Chrome Version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Windows 10 (64-bit)
32G RAM

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Open pagespeed.web.dev.
2. Enter page to test and click Analyze.
3. Results load defaulted to Mobile tab
4. Click Desktop
5. Click back to Mobile

Bam, it hangs, and eventually prompts to "Wait" for the hung tab, ending in the "Out of Memory" error in the attached screen shot.  I have 32G of memory, half of which is unused, it shouldn't be out of memory.  I can reliably reproduce it with any site, just by switching from Mobile to Desktop a couple times.  Earlier it happened when I tried to expand one of the suggestions.

When it crashes, it causes all tabs from pagespeed.web.dev to crash at the same time.

- Issue happens in Chrome and Brave, including incognito windows.
- Issue does not happen in Firefox or Edge.
- It happens to every site you test, including web.dev itself.
- It happens even with all extensions disabled

Comment: Also happening for me over the last week or two.

Answer (score 0):

Safari browser runs it perfectly without any errors!

I've experienced this exact "Aw Snap!" error on all browsers including Chrome, Microsoft Edge but never on Safari.

*I used to own Macbook M1 a few months ago so speaking from pure experience. Unfortunately, I sold it and now I'm on a Windows laptop.*